# How can I remove non-integer ticks while zooming in with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Problem: I am trying to create a pannable/zoomable Linear X axis with ticks on each integer from 0 to a predefined large number (let's say 1000 but could be much higher).  Obviously this will not all fit on the screen and be readable, so I need it to go offscreen and be pannable.  Starting with 0 through 10 is acceptable.  There are a number of problems with my solution so far, but the first being that if I zoom in, D3 automatically adds ticks in between the integers at decimal places to continue to have 10 ticks on the screen.  The second being when I zoom out, the range will display beyond 1000.

A quick note: The data that will be displayed is irrelevant.  The axis has to go from 0 to 1000 regardless if there is a datapoint on 1000 or not so I cannot determine the domain based on my dataset.

Solutions I've tried:

- .ticks().  This lets me specify the number of ticks I want.  However this appears to put all the ticks into the initial range specified.  If I increase the width of the range past the svg size, it spreads out the ticks, but not in any controllable way (to my knowledge).  Additionally I run into performance issues where the panning and zooming. I find this behavior strange since if I don't specify ticks, it makes an infinite number I can pan through without any lag.  I *assume* the lag occurs because it's trying to render all 1000 ticks immediately and the default d3.js functionality renders them dynamically as you scroll.  This seems like a potential solution, but I'm not sure how to execute it.
- .tickValues().  I can provide an array of 0 through 1000 and this works but exhibits the exact same lag behavior as .ticks().  This also doesn't dynamically combine ticks into 10s or 100s as I zoom out.
- .tickFormat().  I can run a function through so that any non-integer number is converted to an empty string.  However, this still leaves the tick line.

Here are the relevant parts of my code using the latest version of D3.js(7.3):

```
const height = 500
const width = 1200

const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 35
}

const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom


const xScale = d3.scaleLinear() 
    .domain([0, 10]) 
    .range([0, innerWidth]) 

const svg = d3.select('svg')  
    .attr("width", width) 
    .attr("height", height) 

svg.append('defs').append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', innerWidth)
    .attr('height', innerHeight)

const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .translateExtent([
        [0, 0],
        [xScale(upperBound), 0]
        ])
    .on('zoom', zoomed)

const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom() 
    .scale(xScale) 

const xAxisG = g.append('g') 
    .style('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .call(xAxis) 
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)

svg.call(zoom)

function zoomed(event) {
    const updateX = event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)
    const zx = xAxis.scale(updateX)
    xAxisG.call(zx)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dealing with the axis' methods, you can simply select the ticks in the container group itself, removing the non-integers:

```
xAxisG.call(zx)
    .selectAll(".tick")
    .filter(e => e % 1)
    .remove();
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const upperBound = 1000
const height = 100
const width = 600

const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 35
}

const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom


const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([0, innerWidth])

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

svg.append('defs').append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', innerWidth)
  .attr('height', innerHeight)

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .translateExtent([
    [0, 0],
    [xScale(upperBound), 0]
  ])
  .on('zoom', zoomed)

const g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale)
  .tickFormat(d => ~~d)

const xAxisG = g.append('g')
  .style('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .call(xAxis)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)

svg.call(zoom)

function zoomed(event) {
  const updateX = event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)
  const zx = xAxis.scale(updateX)
  xAxisG.call(zx)
    .selectAll(".tick")
    .filter(e => e % 1)
    .remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```